# What data structure to be used to achieve the required result?

Tags: java, android, data-structures, spinner

I'm getting the JSON response from server like below

```
{
    "ClassListTaughtByStaff": {
        "ClassTeacherTable": [
            {
                "StandardId": "96e671e2-c1fe-4879-b3bc-88c721292edf",
                "StandardName": "IV",
                "DivisionId": "ac2b6419-a01b-46e1-a5e3-23e84cb04af9",
                "DivisionName": "A"
            }
        ],
        "SubjectTeacherTable": [
            {
                "StandardId": "90da4426-1ba4-4f79-86a5-abb54cf99efb",
                "StandardName": "U.K.G",
                "DivisionId": "ac2b6419-a01b-46e1-a5e3-23e84cb04af9",
                "DivisionName": "A"
            },
            {
                "StandardId": "b2e5f4a8-2abb-4362-a968-e96d9bce3dce",
                "StandardName": "I",
                "DivisionId": "895f06a5-1bf6-488b-87e4-2f8497e27680",
                "DivisionName": "B"
            },
            {
                "StandardId": "08fafc51-3ebe-4e9c-8351-af06dc15ca16",
                "StandardName": "II",
                "DivisionId": "ac2b6419-a01b-46e1-a5e3-23e84cb04af9",
                "DivisionName": "A"
            },
            {
                "StandardId": "08fafc51-3ebe-4e9c-8351-af06dc15ca16",
                "StandardName": "II",
                "DivisionId": "895f06a5-1bf6-488b-87e4-2f8497e27680",
                "DivisionName": "B"
            },
            {
                "StandardId": "ed61b45d-a779-4d65-8330-745853396980",
                "StandardName": "III",
                "DivisionId": "ac2b6419-a01b-46e1-a5e3-23e84cb04af9",
                "DivisionName": "A"
            },
            {
                "StandardId": "ed61b45d-a779-4d65-8330-745853396980",
                "StandardName": "III",
                "DivisionId": "895f06a5-1bf6-488b-87e4-2f8497e27680",
                "DivisionName": "B"
            },
            {
                "StandardId": "96e671e2-c1fe-4879-b3bc-88c721292edf",
                "StandardName": "IV",
                "DivisionId": "895f06a5-1bf6-488b-87e4-2f8497e27680",
                "DivisionName": "B"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm loading the standard name and division names in 2 different spinners using the ArrayList. If you see the images, all standards and divisions are loaded into respective spinners. Now if I select `IV` from standard spinner, division spinner should load `A` and `B`, in the same way if standard `I` is selected then only division `B` should be loaded into division spinner. How can I achieve this?

[image: Standard List]  [image: Division List]

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for change in the first spinner and change the second one accordingly.

You can do something like this:

```
standardNameSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        List<String> values = findDivisionNamesBasedOnStandardName(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1);
        divisionNameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

In **findDivisionNamesBasedOnStandardName** method you must return the related division names regarding the argument as the selected standard name.

***Edit:***

For the mapping part, create a class like:

```
public class Subject {
    String standardId;
    String standardName;

    String divisionId;
    String divisionName;
}
```

and then put all of your results in a `List<Subject>`. Then you can iterate on this list and then `findDivisionNamesBasedOnStandardName` will be something like this:

```
public List<String> findDivisionNamesBasedOnStandardName(String standardName) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Subject subject : mSubjects) {
        if (subject.standardName == standardName) {
            result.add(subject.divisionName);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

where `mSubjects` is the list of all Subjects that you have that you have extracted from your JSON response.

Comment: How to map standards to respective divisions?

Comment: If you see the standard spinner, the standards are repeated. How am I gonna parse the json and store the standards and divisions?

Comment: How did you build the spinners if you haven't parsed the json?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It almost done for me to help you.

- Make two Spinners.
- After that setOnItemSelectedListener's to both.
- make Two methods - `filterOne(int selectedId)`, `filterTwo(int selectedId)`.

pseudo code :

```
Spinner first,second;
SpinnerAdapter firstAdapter, secondAdapter;

filterOne(int id) {
    secondAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(id);
    second.setAdapter(secondAdapter);
}

filerTwo(int id) {
    firstAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(id);
    first.setAdapter(firstAdapter);
}

ArrayList<Date> dates;
CustomSpinnerAdapter(int id) {
    dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    // on click from first spinner. set data to second.
    if(id == 0)  {
        dates.add(new Date(2015, 06, 10));
        dates.add(new Date(2015, 06, 11));
    } else if(id == 1) {
    // on click from second spinner. set data to first.
        dates.add(new Date(2015, 06, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you see the standard spinner, the standards are repeated. How am I gonna parse the json and store the standards and divisions?

Comment: @Aniruddha for parse you can use GSON, for store - HashMap<DIvision, Standard>

Comment: HashMap stores unique values, standard and divisions are repeating here. Please see the JSON

Comment: @Aniruddha not exactly. HashMap stores unique keys, not a values.

Comment: Sorry unique keys. How do I map standard to respective divisions?